# Kotlin with DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE is always updating - not only during creation time

Tags: kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

Using in Kotlin

`@get:DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy = DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
var createdAt: Date? = null`

the value is always changing after saving the entity. Is there something I am missing? Because if I understand it correctly using `DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE` should only update during creation time and not on every update

see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

Is the field also annotated with `@JsonIgnore` or something similar?
I noticed that when you use `@JsonIgnore`, that field will have it's timestamp regenerated each time, but it works properly without.

A possible solution would be to use a dto object without the createdAt field and map it on the current object without the `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: Hi Paolo/ Lennart, the field is not annotated with @JsonIgnore